# Java 11/17 HttpClient - How to try several IPs behind one hostname?

Tags: java, java-11, java-17, inetaddress, java-http-client

How can I configure Java's own "new" (Java 9/11/17) HttpClient to try more than the first found IP adress behind a hostname? There are (at least) two scenarios:

1. A server with IPv4 and IPv6 support:

```
> host localhost
localhost has address 127.0.0.1
localhost has IPv6 address ::1
```

2. One "logical" hostname where the service is delivered by multiple redundant servers:

```
> host frontend.example.com
frontend.example.com has address 245.3.4.5
frontend.example.com has address 246.4.5.6
frontend.example.com has IPv6 address 4f00:5678::19
frontend.example.com has IPv6 address 4f00:7890::20
```

My observation is that HttpClient only tries the *first* delivered address and fails if the service is not reachable under that address. Is there a way to tell it to try *all* assigned IP adresses - `InetAddress.getAllByName()` deliveres them - until a HTTP server can be found at one of them and fails only with "no connection" if *none* of them succeeds.

In the first case, this is relevant if a certain service *only* binds to either the IPv4 or IPv6 address. In the second case, one of the servers or services could be down for maintenance or due to technical problems and the other one serves all incoming requests. So, in my optinion this should be a fairly common requirement for a HTTP client implementation. Still, I have not understood how to archieve this behaviour.

Comment: I'd like to add that ChatGPT - which I asked in parallel - suggests an explicitly programmed loop through all IP addresses. While I find it astonishing that I get such an advise from an AI program, this has already come to my mind, too. However, I'd strongly favor something _within_ HttpClient or its helper classes.

Comment: Is the client configured to follow redirects?  How would a client even know all the potential IP addresses to iterate over them?  If a node of a cluster is down, then the load balancer of that cluster should not attempt to direct requests to the downed node.  A badly configured cluster is not a concern of the client.

Comment: The client should simply iterate over `InetAddress.getAllByName()`. This actually is what most clients (not only HTTP) do when it comes to address resolution. And it's not about "bad configuration": If one of your three load balancers has a hardware failure, it will be in DNS for at least a while. And if a client only tries to connect to this single machine, it will fail - which is not needed as all it needs to do is to try one of the other addresses.

Comment: The new Java HttpClient was designed to be used easily: https://openjdk.org/jeps/110 Special functionalities like multiple DNS and retry wasn't the focus of this client. Thus if you need special functions like retry I would recommend to use one of the available HTTP Java libraries like Apache commons-httpclient.