# Java 17 HttpClient: Multiple IP addresses for a single hostname

Tags: java, inetaddress, java-http-client

We ran into same similar issue like: [Java 11/17 HttpClient - How to try several IPs behind one hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76218224/java-11-17-httpclient-how-to-try-several-ips-behind-one-hostname)

We have a Linux box that has `localhost` IP address (`127.XX.XX.XX`) followed by the internal IP address (`192.XXX.XXX.XX`) listed in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Server application when started up was bound to the internal IP address (`192.XXX..`).

Our client application is based of Java 17 `HttpClient` and the request is sent asynchronously just like below sample code.

Sample Code:

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
.uri(URI.create("https://hostname.domain:port/path"))
.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
.POST(json.body))
.build()
```

When our application ran on the same Linux box, we found that the `HttpClient` library picked up 1st IP address (`127.XXX.XXX.XX`) for `'hostname.domain'` and threw `ClosedChannelException`.

Even if I iterate and get IP addresses of the `'hostname.domain'`, how can I bind `'hostname.domain'` to a particular IP address so that when socket channel is opened it's uses the specified IP address.

I rather use Java's inbuilt library and also since we were not aware of this shortcoming, it's a bit too late in the game to switch to Apache's HTTPClient.

Another thing I tried to circumvent this issue from client side was to enable server to bind to all IP4 and IPv6 addresses. This allowed the httpclient to then connect to the server. I'm not sure if this is a best practice and what issues that might pose.

Any help/advice/best practices to follow, greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The link you shared doesn't point to an actual question. You should also clarify why connecting to the 127.x.x.x IP is causing an error. Is there any limitation in your server? Please be more specific on the environment configuration since we can not guess it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customise "host" header in Java http client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315472/how-to-customise-host-header-in-java-http-client)

Comment: What host name did you use for the https cert that you will need (in most cases) to be using on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dnsjava](https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava) to provide you the IP addresses that are available

Your request would need to pass the `Host` variable

```java
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
.uri(URI.create("https://{ipaddress:port}/path"))
.header("Host", "hostname.domain")
.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

Comment: In addition to making the above code change, you also need to add a system property that will prevent an exception due to "host" being a restricted header: you need to start your application using `java -Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315472/how-to-customise-host-header-in-java-http-client